# Can we use the HasMediaTrait with a pivot class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, media, laravel-medialibrary

I am using this [media library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) for Laravel.

Lets say I have a Pivot class in Laravel 5.5 which is the intermediate table that joins two other tables in a many to many relation.

I have implemented the class like this:

```
class UserTask extends Pivot implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function getCompletedAttribute($value)
    {
        dd($this->getMedia());
    }

    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

}
```

This returns an empty collection despite me having 2 media records assigned to this model in the database.

I think the issue is that this class does not extend `Model` but instead extends `Pivot`. Extending `Pivot` is necessary due to the nature of the many to many relation.

Anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**

If I do this:
`dd(UserTask::find(1)->getMedia());` 
it shows the media objects perfectly fine.

However if I try and fetch the media using the relations in a query builder:

`$sections = $this->model->with('subsections.tasks.users')->get();`

It does not return the media objects as part of the json:

```
"tasks": [
                   {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Create a policy",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nisl nibh, iaculis nec posuere sit amet, fermentum sed orci. Aliquam dignissim, elit at malesuada imperdiet, est leo ullamcorper urna, nec hendrerit lorem lacus vel quam. Fusce mauris massa, pharetra id nisl non, vestibulum tempus est. Curabitur vitae metus non massa volutpat semper ac a ligula. Nunc feugiat pulvinar tortor, viverra hendrerit metus lacinia ut. Etiam efficitur in arcu ut bibendum. Etiam non diam ac odio auctor faucibus sit amet ac metus.",
                        "question": "Have you created a training policy?",
                        "yes_description": "Upload policy to secure, off-site storage",
                        "no_description": "Download template",
                        "high_urgency": 1,
                        "document_upload_required": 1,
                        "active": 1,
                        "created_at": "2018-02-26 09:40:39",
                        "updated_at": "2018-02-26 09:56:33",
                        "pivot": {
                            "section_id": 3,
                            "task_id": 1
                        },
                        "users": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Admin",
                                "email": "admin@example.com",
                                "company_id": null,
                                "is_active": 1,
                                "created_at": "26-02-2018 09:31:15",
                                "updated_at": "2018-02-26 09:31:15",
                                "stripe_id": null,
                                "card_brand": null,
                                "card_last_four": null,
                                "trial_ends_at": null,
                                "pivot": {
                                    "task_id": 1,
                                    "user_id": 1,
                                    "completed": false,
                                    "task": {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "name": "Create a policy",
                                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nisl nibh, iaculis nec posuere sit amet, fermentum sed orci. Aliquam dignissim, elit at malesuada imperdiet, est leo ullamcorper urna, nec hendrerit lorem lacus vel quam. Fusce mauris massa, pharetra id nisl non, vestibulum tempus est. Curabitur vitae metus non massa volutpat semper ac a ligula. Nunc feugiat pulvinar tortor, viverra hendrerit metus lacinia ut. Etiam efficitur in arcu ut bibendum. Etiam non diam ac odio auctor faucibus sit amet ac metus.",
                                        "question": "Have you created a training policy?",
                                        "yes_description": "Upload policy to secure, off-site storage",
                                        "no_description": "Download template",
                                        "high_urgency": 1,
                                        "document_upload_required": 1,
                                        "active": 1,
                                        "created_at": "2018-02-26 09:40:39",
                                        "updated_at": "2018-02-26 09:56:33"
                                    },
                                    "media": []
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
]
```

Comment: how are you going to get the media records ? using `$this->getMedia()` ?

Comment: Yes that gets the media records associated with this model.

Comment: Hi, How did you add Media to the Pivot's Object?